# search index is not deleted when entity value is deleted

Tags: php, doctrine, symfony-2.1

I am working on a job portal's site built in Symfony 2.1. I have implemented `ewz/EWZSearchBundle` for job search process which is as given below:

```
/**
 * Displays a form to create a new Job entity.
 *
 * @Route("/new", name="job_new")
 * @Template("JobBundle:Job:new.html.twig")
 */
public function newAction(Request $request)
{
    $entity = new Job();
    $form   = $this->createForm(new JobType(), $entity);

    if('POST'===$request->getMethod()){
        $form->bind($request);

        if ($form->isValid()) {

            $entity->setOwner($this->getEmployer());

            $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
            $em->persist($entity);
            $em->flush();

            $location = $entity->getLocation();
            $loName = array();
            foreach ($location as $key => $loc) {
                $loName[] = $loc->getName();
            }

            $industry = $entity->getIndustry();
            $inName = array();
            foreach ($industry as $key => $ind) {
                $inName[] = $ind->getTitle();
                }
            $skills = $entity->getSkills();
            $skillName = array();
            foreach ($skills as $key => $skl) {
                $skillName[] = $skl->getTitle();
                }

            $education = $entity->getEducation();
            $educationName = array();
            foreach ($education as $key => $edu) {
                $educationName[] = $edu->getTitle();
                }

            $search = $this->get('ewz_search.lucene');

            $document = new Document();
            $document->addField(Field::keyword('key', $entity->getId()));
            $document->addField(Field::text('title', $entity->getTitle()));
            $document->addField(Field::text('url', $this->generateUrl('job_show', array('slug' => $entity->getSlug()))));
            $document->addField(Field::unstored('body', $entity->getDescription()));
            $document->addField(Field::text('location', implode(" ", $loName)));
            $document->addField(Field::text('industry', implode(" ", $inName)));
            $document->addField(Field::text('skills', implode(" ", $skillName)));
            $document->addField(Field::text('education', implode(" ", $educationName)));


            $search->addDocument($document);
            $search->updateIndex();

            return $this->redirect($this->generateUrl('job_show', array('slug' => $entity->getSlug())));
        }

    }

    return array(
        'entity' => $entity,
        'form'   => $form->createView(),
    );
}
```

It is working very fine when a candidate is searching jobs by any of following fields: location, industry, skills or education. But there are two issues of mine:

1. In this process for every field (locations, skills, industry or education) only one job search is applicable while I want separate search forms, for example in location-wise search, only location field is matched not the other remaining fields.
2. The second problem is when an employer deletes his job, the indexes of deleted jobs are also shown in the search process while after the job was deleted, the index of the deleted job should also be deleted from search index.

I have tried to delete the search index on the time of `job_delete` action by following code:

```
/**
 * Deletes a Job entity
 * @Route("/{slug}/delete", name="job_delete")
 * @Method("POST")
 */
public function deleteAction(Request $request, $slug)
{
    $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
            $entity = $em->getRepository('JobBundle:Job')
           ->findOneBy(array('slug' => $slug));

     if (!$entity) {
            throw $this->createNotFoundException('Unable to find Job entity.');
        }       

    $form = $this->createDeleteForm($entity->getSlug());
    $form->bind($request);       
    if ($form->isValid()) {

    $this->checkOwnerSecurity($entity); 

        $em->remove($entity);
        $em->flush();
        $search = $this->get('ewz_search.lucene');
        $index = $search->getIndex();
        $removePath = 'http://localhost/Jobtook/web/app_dev.php/employer/job/{slug}/delete';
        $hits = $index->find('job_delete' . $removePath);
        foreach ($hits as $hit) {
        $index->delete($hit->id);
        }
    }   

    return $this->redirect($this->generateUrl('job'));
}

private function createDeleteForm($slug)
{
    return $this->createFormBuilder(array('slug' => $slug))
        ->add('slug', 'hidden')
        ->getForm()
    ;
}
```

But by this code when I create many jobs and delete only one job, then all jobs are deleted from the search index even remaining jobs, that still exist in database. I don't know what I am doing wrong.